# Patron observador en UML

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño, observable

Quiero agregar un servicio de notificación a nuestros suscriptores. Los suscriptores podrán elegir sus secciones favoritas. Cuando se publique un nuevo artículo en alguno de ellos, se les enviará un correo electrónico con el título del mismo. Queremos ofrecer una solución que evite el acoplamiento entre suscriptores y artículos. Tenemos un servidor de correo EMailServer. No necesita conocer los detalles de su configuración o el método sendEMail. Estos detalles están encapsulados en esta clase, a cuyos Servicios se accede a través de la aplicación de patrón Singleton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El patrón de responsabilidad me queda claro, usaré observador, pero no sé si lo tengo bien implementado.

También había pensado en implementar el patrón de diseño del controlador pero esto genera más dudas sobre cómo traducirlo al uml, de momento mi implementación del observador es la siguiente, no sé si es correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice fue que el observador será el servidor de correo que notificará al suscriptor de un nuevo artículo de su sección favorita, mientras que lo observable estará relacionado con el tema específico que es el artículo.

No sé si está bien, pero eso es lo que me viene a la mente

En cuanto al patrón de diseño, tengo más dudas debido al singleton.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la arquitectura (C/S, P2P, nCapas, Web, centralizado, etc)?

Comment: @Sal la arquitectura es de 3 capas,presentacion,logica y datos.

Answer (score 1):

Un observador no cabe bien en este caso, a menos que implementes otros patrones.

Este patrón requiere a dos actores definidos: el observador y el observable.
Pareciera que el caso es: que los suscriptores observen la sección;
mientras planteas que el servidor de correo observa los artículos.

Un artículo que no ha sido creado no puede ser observable, aunque en cierto punto
podría serlo si pasara de un estado borrador a publicado, por ejemplo.
De lo contrario ¿qué podría ser observable?:

- Un creador ó constructor ó publicador de artículos
- Un administrador de secciones
- ¿Una sección? dependería de sus métodos.

Posiblemente por lo anterior has creado `SubjectArticleObservable`,
que terminaría fungiendo como [delegado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) de la observación:
*"No me veas a mí, véelo a él"*.

¿Quién sería el observador: el servidor de correo o el suscriptor?.
Su fueran los suscriptores, éstos no los tendrías en memoria -a menos que
implementes un [Object Pool](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o))-, y considerando que se podrían (de)suscribir de un instante a otro,
la lista de observadores debería considerarse incierta en todo momento y determinada por un instante.
Por lo tanto, suena razonable delegar también la observación: *"no me avises a mí, avísale a él"*.

Por todo lo anterior, pareciera mas adecuado que `EMailServer` sea un [mediador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o))
entre el observable y el suscriptor.